# RESTful API call: why does it work on browser but has issues when using Python Requests?

Tags: python-requests, restful-url

If I go to this public REST URL on my browser, it returns a JSON instantaneously and correctly:
https://dataminer.pjm.com/dataminer/rest/public/api/topics

However, if I try to access it using Requests, there's a long delay.

```python
import requests

url = ("https://dataminer.pjm.com/dataminer"
       "/rest/public/api/topics")
hdrs = {"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"}
resp = requests.get(url, verify=False, headers=hdrs)
print(resp.content)
```

When it finally loads, the number 479 is appended to the beginning and 0 is appended to the end of the JSON:

```
479
[{"topicID":1,
... content snipped ...
 "endDate":"2014-08-02T04:00:00Z"}]
0
```

I've tried replicating the HTTP request using the headers I obtained using Chrome Developer tools, but same deal.

What is different between what my browser is doing and what Requests is doing? How do I debug this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first, that did not load instantaneously for me in the browser, but that isn't exactly the problem.

If you inspect the headers, the server is sending back

```
Transfer-Encoding: chunked, chunked
```

Which I've seen before with Tomcat and .NET servers. With that said, requests has to continue trying to read from the socket because there's no `Content-Length` and the server does not immediately close the connection or send the proper termination byte because it's actually not doing the wrong thing. Like a seriously horrible thing.

The proper header would be:

```
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

And then a body sent like the one you see:

```
479
...
0
```

will be valid and terminate quickly.

Requests cannot do anything differently with what it's given by the server. We do exactly as the specification tells us. Browsers on the other hand often take liberties and do extra work which encourages this sort of bad behaviour by servers and website developers.

Answer (score 1):

First note: this isn't explicitly a `requests` problem. I believe this behavior is set in the underlying Python http library: `urllib2`, I think? I did test that while diagnosing this issue.

I ran into this problem from the server side. We were running a Tomcat instance, and someone had instructed us to add `Transfer-encoding: chunked` to the response headers. It was done in the application.

When I ran across this issue (it was `curl`, not a browser, that was able to get the content without trouble; but still the same discrepancy vs. the behavior of `requests`), I finally figured out that setting the `Transfer-encoding` header at the application level is a bad practice. Tomcat decides *for itself* whether to use chunked encoding, on the outbound Response construction, long after the application has anything to say about it.

Unfortunately, Tomcat doesn't *replace* the header value when it makes that decision. It simply adds *another value* to the header. This results in exactly the situation that sigmavirus24 describes. I wouldn't be surprised if this same circumstance occurs in .NET servers, since the basic behaviors of enterprise server designs are pretty well convergent.

Serverside devs: try not to set the `Transfer-encoding` explicitly at all, unless you're sure that the server isn't handling it on a lower level.

Pythonistas using `requests`: I haven't done this yet (and I have a project that should use this) but it should be easy to detect this condition and give a specific error message. I will post something when I do, now that I'm reminded of it.

`requests` committers: I suggest this issue be explicitly explained in the documentation. I'd be happy to send a pull request if you'd like; or you're welcome to just adapt anything I've said here.

`urllib2` committers: consider the possibility that handling duplicate identical values for `Transfer-encoding` need not be a big problem, and that, given the widespread vulnerability of server designs to issuing unneeded duplications, it might make sense to collapse duplicate values for this header into single values before processing a message body.

Comment: Speaking on behalf of the requests core development team, we're very happy to have pull requests from new contributors :)